# Hide loading popup of Java WebStart?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

Is there any way to run JNLP on Windows without display this popup? It's annoying when the operation run periodically.

[image: Java Web Start download popup]

Thanks

Comment: Even in the case of .NET, the same thing cannot be done when deploying a ClickOnce .NET app... the progress bar will be there for a reason, though :)

Comment: Maybe, this can give a clue: **Why does Java Web Start always reload JAR files from IIS server?**

`If a timestamp of the file on the IIS server is in the future IIS returns current-time as last-modified time. This makes Java Web Start to reload the JARs since time-stamp is always newer.`

Comment: My application does the updating jars correctly. However, it still has the popup in very short time. But the PC is very week, so it's still annoying.

Comment: You can try offline mode (-offline option) - I really don't know what it does, but expect it not to check for updates.

Comment: @KDM: But offline mode is not our purpose when using jnlp ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide the download window, you can only customize the splash screen:

http://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/changing_the_java_web_start